# How do I keep the Maya civilization running

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, alternate-history, diseases

The Maya civilization was the most advanced civilization in the Americas before the conquest by the Spanish. They had incredible advancements in astrology, writing and technology and were the only civilization in the new world to domesticate an animal, the llama.

But none the less, like every new world culture, they were destroyed. But does it have to be this way? Is it possible for me to keep the Maya civilization running to this day? If so, what is the smallest change I can make to history to allow them to live?

Comment: @Nimrod that is in no way a small change

Comment: You do know the Mayan Empire fell considerably before the Spanish arrived.  What Caused their downfall is a mostly a mystery.  It would be easier to answer this for the Aztecs or Incas who were still around.

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear Really? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_civilization#Contact_period_and_Spanish_conquest_.281511.E2.80.931697_AD.29), the Spanish did indeed conquer and/or drive out the Mayans. Now it wouldn't be the first time Wikipedia was wrong, but it seems well supported by the sources. Can you clarify?

Comment: @type_outcast there were still Mayan but the empire has already fallen far from its height scroll up to classic Mayan collapse (same wiki page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the great Mesoamerican civilizations, the Mayans were actually one of the earliest. They have a long archaic period, with their roots being founded around 8000 BCE.

By the time that the Spanish came to the New World in the 15th century, the Mayans were a modest, village-based people. This is because the great and advanced empire that you're referring to existed within their Classic Era, which ended six hundred years earlier.

The Classic Era of the Mayans was marked by the creation of their most famous monuments, massive degrees of urbanization, and a political system akin to Ancient Greece. This was their culture in their prime.

But this Era ended long before any Old World humans had the chance to taint it with their grimy, greedy hands. When the Spanish came, their culture wasn't exactly in a Golden Age. Needless, to say, they were a ghost of their former selves; and growing civilizations like the Incas and the Aztecs dominated the area.

The reason for the fall of the Mayan collapse is uncertain. Some people believe that the Mayans exhausted their resources and couldn't support their large population. Others think its more likely that they killed each other in war, and their political infrastructure fell apart. Or, thirdly, some large disaster wiped them out.

Following this collapse, the Mayans abandoned their major cities and spread out into the small communities that the Spanish found when they came to America; similar to but considerably more impressive than the small populations of Mayan people that can be found today.

So to answer your question, it's smartest just to pretend that the "Collapse of the Classical Era" never happened. Whether a civil war or a natural disaster, simply have it never occur. Then, when the Spanish invade, they would have a much larger, more complex, and more formidable army to fend them off and preserve their culture with.

**TL;DR**

Nobody really knows what happened to the Mayans. It was either lack of resources, a series of wars/civil wars, or a major natural disaster that led to their downfall. The smallest change to history that you can make is to simply prevent any of those from happening.

Comment: Your answer is perfect if it were in the history.se but for worldbuilding you need to elaborate more on how it could survive to the present day. I don't think the spanish, with gunpowder and disease would have much problem wiping out the mayan.

Comment: I think this is a perfect answer. We don't know why the decline happened but if it hadn't they'd have fended off the invaders. Make up a reason that it collapsed and then prevent that from happening. Then the Mayan civilization is vibrant and strong when the Spanish come.

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm not sure that "Simply being around" would have prevented the destruction of the mesoamerican civilisations by the Conquistadors - the Aztecs were by all rights a formidable fighting force that had subdued every other culture in their region - it didn't stop their downfall.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the Mayans or the Incas are a better choice. Either way, have them go the Japanese way:

- Have them well organized and on a war footing when the Europeans arrive. Perhaps they have just finished a civil war, or a war with another American power. They manage to contain the very first incursions to a few "treaty ports".
- Have several competing European powers arrive at the same time. Some want conquest, others want trade, yet others want to hinder their enemies.
- Move the Thirty Years' War up by more than a century and involve Spain and Portugal by a larger degree. Have Hus take the role of Luther.

Events in Europe mean fewer Conquistadors, rival traders give them a breathing room to adopt gunpowder and metal.

---

Or a completely different option, introduce a plague endemic to the Americas and give the Americans some resistance. After contact, the Europeans both in America and at home die in droves. By the time the survivors have immunity, there will be more rebuilding closer to home.